# Buscador para tabla en Google Sites

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-sites

quisiera saber como agregar un buscador a una pagina de google sites para mostrar datos de una tabla insertada de google sheets. Hasta el momento he probado con Google Custom Search Engine pero no muestra resultados de una tabla insertada.